# Код не хочет исполняться. p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let i=1; i<100; i++) {
    circle (width/2, height/2, i);
  }
}
```

По идее должна быть создана анимация с увеличивающимся в диаметре кругом, но на исходе получаю сразу круг с диаметром 100px. Подскажите, что изменить что бы все таки получить анимацию

Comment: Добавить задержку в исполнение функции, к примеру

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что на экран выводится то, что получилось после **полного выполнения** метода `draw()`.

Следовательно, все круги уже нарисованы к показу кадра.

Самое простое решение этой проблемы будет выглядеть так:

```
let d = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  circle(width/2, height/2, d);
  if (d < 100) {
    d++;
  }
}
```